# When multiple Smiths work together to create items, can one apply feat to reduce the total cost?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, crafting, pricing

If multiple characters are working together to meet the prerequisites for crafting an item and only one of the characters has a feat to reduce the cost, are they allowed to apply it? For instance if one character knows Fabricate, has the Craft Magic Arms and Armor feat, and is at least the 5th caster level, can another character with the Gold Dwarf Dweomersmith feat (from Races of Faerun) assist them in forging an Ioun Blade (from the Arms and Equipment Guide) to reduce the crafting cost by 5%?

Likewise, are similar feats such as Extraordinary Artisan, Apprentice: Craftsman, Shield Dwarf Warder affected in the same way?

Comment: As a GM i think [Fabricate](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/fabricate.htm) would ruin any cooperation efforts. How are your workers supposed to contribute anything within a **Duration: Instantaneous** time-span?

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen The spell Fabricate is a defined prerequisite for creating a Ioun Blade. It must be provided each day during the creation process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Peregrin Took correctly points out](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/202370/when-multiple-smiths-work-together-to-create-items-can-one-apply-feat-to-reduce/#comment-553141) the Prerequisites section of [Magic Item Descriptions](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicItemBasics.htm#prerequisites) in the Dungeons Master Guide (DMG) explicitly states that several people can cooperate to craft an item, each supplying whichever part of the prerequisites of the item they desire.

Therefore my answer changes to yes, any character should be able to supply a relevant crafting feat to the process (such as the Gold Dwarf Dweomersmith feat in your question).

### Original Answer

The rules are vague on this.

The Dungeons Master Guide (DMG) says no(?) on page 282, as it only specifies that other spellcasters may supply the spells. The argument here being that if they intended for feats to work with cooperative crafting efforts, they would have said so.

Magic Item Compendium (MIC) says yes for all cooperative efforts (except The XP cost must always be paid by the character who supplies the item creation feat required by the item, no matter how many other characters cooperate in its creation.) on page 232.

The best answer is probably "ask your GM".

Comment: In the Magic Item Descriptions on page 216 of the DMG the prerequisites needed to create a magic item (which can also be provided by different characters) comprise "feats, spells,
and miscellaneous requirements such as level, alignment, and
race or kind" ….